# Why adding org.slf4j.api to dependencies causes Application not found in the registry error?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, eclipse-rcp

I am absolutely don't understand if there is any logic in RCP behavior.

I am experimenting with logging inside views.

My application was running fine until I added dependency on `org.slf4j.api`

Nothing else was changed in the code.

But this dependency change caused that absurdic error

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-01-10 17:25:08.072
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "Try_EclipseRCPView_03.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLaunche
...
```

If I remove dependency, error disappears.

Why?????

**UPDATE**

Finally Eclipse crashed and deleted all my files (wiped out, it's not a joke). I was not thinking it is even possible. Be careful Eclipse platform is written by idiots. I am very very sad.

Comment: Sounds like a dependency issue. Try pressing the button "Add required plugins" in your product configuration after adding `org.slf4j.api`. Are more errors shown before this one, something like a list of bundles which were not resolved?

Comment: I have no product. I am running under Eclipse.

Comment: "Add required plugins" can also be done in the "Run Configuration", in the "Plug-ins" tab.

Comment: I believe that there are some plugins may missing. But what does error message mean? Why doesn't it say that plugin VERYIMPORTANTPLUGIN2.0 is missing? Why it is saying that no application in the registry?

Comment: Because the plugin dependencies cannot be found the application is considered to be incomplete and is not added to the registry.

Comment: If the process of addition fails, it should be evident, why