# Eclipse crashed and deleted all my work

Tags: eclipse, undelete

Eclipse crashed and deleted all project files, including written by me and XML files from another program which were not related to Eclipse.

Is it possible to force Eclipse or JVM to use trash can, so that if it goes mad and delete everything, files could restored.

**UPDATE**

Files were definitely wiped out. This was checked with third party file managers. Also entire disc were searched for traces.

Some good news is that Eclipse history remained. This allowed to restore some files I changed from Eclipse. But this project was consisting of multiple other files, that were written not by me (taken from other libraries) or contained some data I was editing not in Eclipse (like XML or raw data).

All these files were wiped out by Eclipse.

If this would not happen to me I would also say it is unlikely. But it has happened.

The problem is somehow related with

(1) Eclipse

(2) Maven (m2e)

(3) Eclipse RCP

(4) Tycho

At some moment Eclipse started to show numerous error windows and I was to kill the process. After that I found files absent.

So I need some extra protection layer.

**UPDATE 2**

Crash repeated. This is a message during file wiping out:

[image]

This time I was not using Maven and Tycho.

**UPDATE 3**

Third crash.

Crash occurs only after error `Application ... could not be found in the registry`, which itself buggie.

[image]

**UPDATE 4**

Still unable to reproduce situation from scratch...

Comment: I did not see such feature. But you should check in your workspace. normally it is located in `~/workspace` folder. I hope you did not misunderstand workspace with eclipse directory

Comment: Files are wiped out. I was not thinking it is possible.

Comment: How are you so sure that files are wiped out ? Even when we intentionally delete a project, the contents in the workspace wont be deleted unless we check the checkbox to do so. At least do you remember what is your workspace directory ? normally eclipse wont delete them.

Comment: Maybe your hard drive is failing. See http://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/

Comment: @RobinGreen SMART is ok on my drives.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** I think [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045536/why-adding-org-slf4j-api-to-dependencies-causes-application-not-found-in-the-reg) you were working on an Eclipse RCP plugin or something like that when this happened.

So you probably broke your Eclipse in some fashion. Do not trust anything Eclipse tells you at this point! Look at the actual filesystem!

---

> Eclipse crashed and deleted all project files, including written by me and XML files from another program which were not related to Eclipse.

That's highly unlikely. (Especially if those XML files were not in the workspace. But even if they were, it's very unlikely.) You probably opened a new workspace without realising it, or maybe Eclipse has some bug where it won't show you files that are actually there. Or maybe you accidentally switched to the wrong view (in Java the normal view for files is Package Explorer, if I remember correctly).

Or maybe you were storing your workspace on a USB stick (aka pen drive) or network drive and you accidentally disconnected from it without realising it.

Check in the workspace (the *actual* workspace you were using at the time, not the workspace you are now using, which, as I said, might not be the same thing), using Windows Explorer (if you are using Windows) or Finder (if you are using a Mac) or using `ls` (if you are using something else). Are the files really gone?

Comment: Unfortunately all your suggestions are not true. Files are gone physically. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

**This Was My Fault**

I was setting up a workspace location pointing to project folder and also setting clear workspace checkbox.

::shame::

Comment: Ouch! In future... check your projects into git, and push regularly to a remote git server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not so much your fault.
Eclipse has very weird mechanisms. It should indicate what it's going to delete if you select that clear option.
It also behaves buggy frequently.

Many bugs never get resolved for 10 years or more, for instance this one that deletes your entire folder/project if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - ><kbd>Z</kbd> in some cases

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344724